# How do you query for currently executing DDL queries in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, ddl

Note that I'm asking about DDL queries in particular. From the documentation, it's not clear how to do this or if this is even possible.

[STL_DDLTEXT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_DDLTEXT.html) seems to only show **finished** DDL queries.

[STV_RECENTS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_RECENTS.html) and [STV_INFLIGHT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_INFLIGHT.html) don't document whether they show regular queries vs DDL; from experience I have never seen any DDL queries in those system views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STV_RECENTS` does capture the currently active and recently run queries. The queries include both DDL and DML. I know this because I use it in my script. 
 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.